# Common exception handling for rolled back transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

We have an application using Java and Hibernate. We use optimistic locking and a relational database. We have a common situation where we have a pool of resources, that two different users try to modify at the same time. One user is able to edit the resources, another user gets "stack-trace" on the screen. What is a common way to handle these situations? We could use pessimistic locking but that would significantly degrade the performance of the application...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a stack trace, notify the user that there was a concurrent update to the data they were working on, and force them to refresh it before saving.  Try to preserve whatever they have edited or your users will hate you.

Or were you looking for a technical solution?

Comment: I would also be interested in technical aspects. If a transaction gets rolled back due to that another transaction already performed writes on the data, is a specific exception always thrown? If yes, then it would be easy to handle it consistently in the same way across the application.

Comment: I believe there are multiple results that represent an optimistic lock failure.  The exception will have a an error attached to it, so you can call getErrorCode() and see if it matches one or more values that you know represent a "rollback".  For development, it's probably easiest to just cause the error and look at the error code that's returned, then plug that into your code.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that a hibernate optimistic lock failure will not underlying SQLException related to it, since it's not really a database exception.  It's just an update that effects no rows.